# How to add valid SSL to heroku custom damoain

Tags: ssl, heroku, dnsimple

I need to add SSL to my heroku custom domain. I have done through a wide variety of keys/crts/pems etc. All I want to do is have SSL on a heroku wildcard custom domain.

I bought a wildcard ssl certificate. I have a plan on DNSimple.com, and now I need to upload everything to the server.

What files do I need  to add? How can I get them?

I have a Certificate and a private key from DNSimple, now I understand I have to upload a CRS file to DNSimple. Can someone offer a step-by-step, heroku's is very poorly designed and convoluted.

Right now, chrome gives me a big red user warning.

Thanks,

Brian

Answer (score 1):

Hope you have gone through Heroku documentation for DNS simple-

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-certificate-dnsimple

If still not working, let me know. Will post the steps needed to do this.

Comment: I poured through that. Much conflicting info. was eventually able to figure it out. I'm going to post a step-by-step as soon as I get a good nights sleep